# Unexpected Awk results with sh -c

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to sudo a command that uses Awk, and it looks like awk works differently inside sh -c.

```
echo '1 2' | awk '{print $2}'
```

2

```
sh -c "echo '1 2' | awk '{print $2}'"
```

1 2

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use double quotes, therefore `$2` is evaluated. The inner single quotes don't affect this anymore.
If `$2` is empty, you are basically calling `awk '{print }'`. Consequently, you get the whole input line as output.

You could for example escape the `$` with a backslash: `\$2`

Comment: @Michael: You can see the behavior described by Maxi by using the `-x` option of the shell to show a trace: `sh -xc "echo '1 2' | awk '{print $2}'"`